# unable to sort a javascript string array which contains number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which contains the below values and I am trying to sort the values in the array using arr.sort() but not seeing any change in output, it's still returning the same array format

```
var arr = ["swagger-regional-1.20.1.yaml", 
 "swagger-regional-1.20.2.yaml", 
 "swagger-regional-1.7.0.yaml", 
 "swagger-regional-1.8.2.yaml", 
 "swagger-regional-1.8.3.yaml", 
 "swagger-regional-1.8.4.yaml", 
 "swagger-regional-1.8.5.yaml", 
 "swagger-regional-1.9.0.yaml",
 "swagger-regional-1.9.1.yaml", 
 "swagger-regional-1.9.2.yaml"];

arr.sort()
```

Expected output:

```
["swagger-regional-1.7.0.yaml", 
 "swagger-regional-1.8.2.yaml", 
"swagger-regional-1.8.3.yaml", 
"swagger-regional-1.8.4.yaml", 
"swagger-regional-1.8.5.yaml", 
"swagger-regional-1.9.0.yaml",
"swagger-regional-1.9.1.yaml", 
"swagger-regional-1.9.2.yaml",
"swagger-regional-1.20.1.yaml", 
"swagger-regional-1.20.2.yaml"]
```

Comment: `20` sorts before `7` in a lexical sort.

Comment: Take a look at [string.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)